Serving part of a web application as a python package for people to install, ok to do?
Background
To preface, I am building a database for the construction of a timing detector. However, I am very new to software engineering and database development. I have been building a website using Flask (following this tutorial) that will track the shipments, tests, assembly, etc... of the different components. I am a fresh physics undergrad trying to figure out the best way to approach these software engineering problems!
Problem
For the tests and assembly steps, I made a standard JSON format for every test using Pydantic. A bunch of different collaborators will have to get their data into this format so I would like to offer a bit of software and these Pydantic models for them to validate their JSON before upload (I will of course do the validation too).
I figured I could make this part of the website into a Python package! It would be cool to do a pip install and you get access to this software. Now I will be developing the rest of my app very closely with these Pydantic models (caching of data and visualization be a part of the objects). Executing this in a way that feels right has been difficult so here are the options I am considering in no particular order:

"correct way": have the package live separately in its own folder in the root directory of my project which is all one big git repository. Then learn, and make a GitLab CI to automate this somehow (or use OKD somehow here, I use this to host my website). Then import the package into my application where I need it like everyone would.

Downsides: For every little tweak I do I would have to somehow redeploy to PyPi right? Seems very cumbersome. Same if it lived in its own repository.


My Way: Have the package at the root directory and have it imported into my application like it was pip installed but it is just reading the source code. Then manually update it to PyPI when I want to with some potentially beefy command line interface code that I would write.

no package: Just force all the utilities through API endpoints.
This keeps things a lot cleaner probably especially with versions.

Downsides: I have had some pushback on doing everything through an API, not everyone knows how to use one. The package would be more friendly but maybe this is the best way.



I appreciate anybody's 2 cents as I am very new to web development and databases.
TLDR
How and would you serve a piece of a web application as a Python package for people to use? Is this a mess to implement or something that is done fairly often? I am fairly new to software engineering and web development so anybody's 2 cents is appreciated

I think the term "web application" here is adding some confusion to the question,   Something being a web application generally implies that users can access it using just their web browser (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23140462 ).    If users have to separately download and install some other application or package, and particularly if they need a bunch of other dependencies like the Python interpreter, then I would say that what you're building isn't really a web application at all.

Oh shoot sorry @BenCottrell I gave a confusing explanation, I should have provided more information. Based on the link you sent, I would say my project is a web app, that serves web pages that use server-side processing. What I am trying to do exactly is provide some software for users, if they want, to get (or generate) their data in a specific JSON format the web app expects for assembly/tests (that is validated by Pydantic). This is only one part of the web app (there are shipment, part summary, and part registration pages too).

This is difficult to visualise. Users are expected to use this, but it will change frequently? So if users do install it, it'll be out of date? Data has to be in specific JSON format, but where does that data come from? Write yourself some "user stories" and example workflows, that may clarify this a bit. Is the thing on github already?

Ok, I will do this thank you. I think the user stories would be helpful. For what it is worth, this is the piece of code I was thinking of having as a package, https://gitlab.cern.ch/hswanson/mtd-etl-app/-/blob/dev/application/data_models.py?ref_type=heads or more of a wrapper for all of these pydantic models.

Do not distribute standalone software to people. I repeat: do not distribute standalone software to people. Unless it is absolutely necessary or it is the nature of the software (e.g. video games).
Maintenance is a nightmare. Versioning has so many consequences. First, you need to distribute each new version. Which already is painful. But what is worse, it is likely you have to support old versions. At least up until some point. Because you can't force people to actually use newer software. Unless you want to experience their fury.
So just keep everything in your web app. If you want, you can give your users a separate software. But what I suggest is: software as a service. You can setup a validation service for their data, why not? You still have similar versioning issues, but at least you have full control now, and can actually enforce stuff on people if needed.
Trust me, it is a lot easier if everything is under your control. People are just... Eh...
The only reason to actually distribute such software is if the data is huge, say in GB or at least hundreds of MB. Otherwise, don't bother.
But if you decide otherwise, then it would be beneficial to keep such package in entirely separate, independent repository. It is easier to track changes that way. And since you have to setup some build and publish process anyway, then there's no benefit of keeping it together with other code.

The software wouldn't be required to input into the website or through the API but just there to help if they want it. I do not know if this introduces complexity though. There will be thousands of tests and assemblies needed to upload ~100,000+ tests and assemblies. Sorry for not giving a better background, I am learning what the important relevant points are.

Everyone hates python package management. It's a particularly annoying case. If it changes frequently that's even worse.

It will change pretty frequently or will be updated and added to. Eventually, it will reach a steady state. This is a good point,  I think I will just wait until then. Thank you.
